# Cast an Object wtih different classes inside

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I´m triying to cast an object that comes from two differents classes.
I get the object from a HQL query like this:

```
select F.title, F.length, F.specialFeatures 
from Film F 
left join F.filmActors X 
inner join X.actor A 
where A.firstName like 'E%'
```

The object gets part from Actors, Film and FilmActors. 
The problem appears when I try to cast the object:

```
Film fl = (Film) o;
```

And shows this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to sakila.entity.Film
at Formulario_AD04.mostrarResultados(Formulario_AD04.java:76)
```

How can I cast the object if it comes from `sakila.entity.film`, `sakila.entity.Actor`, etc...?

Comment: As the error message shows, such a query returns a list containing instances of Object[] (each array containing 3 elements: a title, a length, and a specialFeatures). Not instances of Film. Also note that this query, contrary to what you claim, only gets properties from Film. Not from Actore. Not from FilmActors.

Comment: If I try another query like this one: "from Film F where F.title like 'E%'"  I can cast the Object to Film without problems, so if the first query don´t contain part of Actors or FilmActors why is it not working? Thanks for your help and sorry for the grammar....

Comment: Well, if your query selects films, you get films back. If it selects tuples of 3 values, you get tuples of 3 values back. Where these 3 values come from doesn't change anything, and is irrelevant. What matters is your select clause. `select f` is different from `select f.title, f.length`.

Comment: Then it was easier than i thought. Now it is working correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to better understand what is the type of the result list from an hibernate query.list() method.

This is a `List<Film>` where `Film` is a hibernate entity if the query projection is simple like :

`select F from Film F`

But in your case, your projection is

`select S1, S2, S2`

where S1, S2 and S3 are three scalars (according to the query defined in `consultaActor`)

So the actual type of the output list is `List<Object[]>` hence the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to  sakila.entity.Film` where you try to cast an `Object[]` to a `Film`, which is illegal.